# Looking for help with a lattice point graph problem.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm given a graph that has 5 sets of points on it (1,1), (2,2) , (3,2) , (1,-1) , and (4,-1). The question is asking to prove that at least one pair of these points has a midpoint which is also a lattice point. However, a lattice point is a point in which its coordinates are integers, so doesn't that automatically mean that all of the midpoints are lattice points? And does that not mean that any two points would always have a midpoint that is a lattice point?

Comment: Please do not deface questions with good answers. Others have devoted effort to answer your question; deleting the question is disrespectful of their effort and prevents others from benefiting from your question and its answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick two points $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$. Then their midpoint is $(\frac{a+c}{2}, \frac{b+d}{2})$.

What you might notice, is that the only thing stopping the midpoint being a lattice point are the 2s on the denominator. Hence, we have that $a+c$ and $b+d$ are even. The only way that can happen is if $a$ and $c$ are the same parity, and in addition $b$ and $d$ are also the same parity.

Now consider this: there are only 4 possibilities for the parities of the given lattice points. You have (odd, odd), (odd, even), (even, odd) and (even, even). But you're given 5 lattice points, so by the pigeonhole principle you must double up on one of the four types. Find the midpoint of those two and you've got your lattice midpoint.

Comment: Ah! Which explains why the question was specific to 5 points, so in a set of 5 points there is only one set that has a lattice midpoint?

Comment: There could be more than one (e.g. points where all the coordinates are even), but the idea is that there will always be at least one